# Gradle and Java: what is the correct way of calling the system properties in test task

Tags: java, gradle

In my gradle project I have a test task and setting up some system properties reading from the gradle.property file this way:

```
systemProperties["property1.username"] = property1_username
```

And some properties this way :

```
systemProperty "property2.id",project.getProperty("property2.id")
```

What is the difference between both? The difference I saw was that property2 not able to work with the systemProperties so I went through the different route.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both examples are basically valid ways to register system properties for your Gradle [`Test`](https://docs.gradle.org/3.4/javadoc/org/gradle/api/tasks/testing/Test.html) task.

In the first example, you access the [`systemProperties`](https://docs.gradle.org/3.4/javadoc/org/gradle/api/tasks/testing/Test.html#getSystemProperties()) property directly, via a hidden getter (which is a [`Groovy feature`](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2073053/groovy-hip-tip--to-use-or-not-to-use-setters-and-getters.html)). This property is a [`Map`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) and in Groovy, you can add an entry directly with the subscript operator `[]`. You use your string `"property1.username"` as entry key and the value of the expression `property1_username` as entry value. The expression must be resolvable in the Gradle [`Project`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/Project.html) scope, but [Gradle properties](https://docs.gradle.org/3.3/userguide/build_environment.html), e.g. from the `gradle.properties` file, are added automatically to this scope.

In your second example, you are using the [`systemProperty`](https://docs.gradle.org/3.4/javadoc/org/gradle/api/tasks/testing/Test.html#systemProperty(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object)) method of the `Test` class. It takes two arguments (a name and a value) and adds a new entry to the `Map` mentioned above. Groovy allows to omit unnecessary brackets for method calls. To get the system property value, the second method argument, you call the `getProperty` method of your `Project` object, which also resolves a property in the Gradle `Project` scope.

I do not know, why your property2 did not work with the `systemProperties` approach, maybe its a simply typo, since both ways should work like a charm. Feel free to work with the linked docs to learn how different methods in the Gradle ecosystem work.